# Pass selected value from one form to another - ms access

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have an access database which has one form, asset_information in the source of which some fields are restricted to values in another table ([brand name] and [model name]).

I am trying to write a 'popup' or 'modal' form for the asset information form which will allow users to open a search form for the model or brand, search existing ones and then either select the model or brand or create a new one.

Example:

An user clicks here [on the first form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCvfc.png),
[image]

After that, [this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/talri.png) pops up - user searches and clicks in one of the results then clicks 'select model'
[image]

That returns the model_id selected by the user from the popup form to the original form.

Googling has not helped much, can anyone point me in the right direction? Should I be using the openargs on the second form, or the first and second form? Or should I be using something else entirely?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here? You are already passing values from the pop-up with the `model_id.

Comment: How? Does the use of a pop up form pass the primary key back to the original form?

Comment: Sorry I thought you were already doing that as you said, "That returns the model_id selected by the user from the popup form to the original form."  What you can do is in the code behind the "Select Model" button, assign the selected value to the specific textbox control on your main form, prior to closing the pop-up form.